# WinForms status strip label text inverted

Tags: winforms, menu, statusstrip

I have a WinForms application with Status strip which shows label on the right.
But, when I launch the application and click on some other window to take focus away from it before it has opened, this is what I see in status strip

[Bad status strip](http://postimg.org/image/lzgitvs1h/)

instead of

[Expected status strip](http://postimg.org/image/linn09azr/)

I get the correct thing if I wait for the application to open up completely without it losing focus.

Has anybody seen something like this before?
Please feel free to ask for any additional information for properties set for form and status strip.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My crystal balls says that you forgot to mention that you changed the RightToLeft property to Yes.  That's only appropriate when you localize your form to Hebrew or Arabic.  Languages that write right-to-left.

Comment: @Hans Yes your crystal ball is indeed right but without setting Right to Left the controls show up on the left side. Or should I use the methods already in some SO questions of having a label with empty text stretching to keep useful labels on the right.